# execute code when loading view

Tags: iphone, ios4

in the new os 4.0 when you leave the application it enter background, but when you relaunch it it doesnt load any code, i want my application to execute a specific method when going back into the app. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should look into using this delegate method `- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application`

More info: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground: